# How to save battery life for notebooks always connected to the AC grid

Tags: laptop, battery, power-management, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Toshiba Satellite L50-A-161 with a Li-ion battery.
The removal of my Toshiba battery is quite complicated: it is necessary to open the case unscrewing 14 screws and remove the dvd unit. The battery itself is fixed to the motherboard with 4 screws and a pin connector. See this instructive [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IG0lW7t92bI).

This kind of notebook was plainly designed to prevent the user from removing the battery.
Knowing this, my main concern is that I need to use my notebook daily for a prolonged period of time, many hours a day, often from morning to night, and I rarely need the battery as a source of power, working in places where the AC power is always available. To some extent I would mainly need and use the battery as an AC filter.

With this in mind, I am wondering what practice suits me best: keep the laptop connected to the AC grid and calibrate the battery once a month with occasional partial discharges/charges would be safe? [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries/comment) writes that “Most users do not remove the AC power, and this practice is safe”, but of course this goes against the “Partial charge better than a full charge” guidance rule: keeping the laptop connected to the AC grid would keep the battery always at 100% charge.

Besides Battery University points out that "charging stops when the Li-ion battery is full" and that it is not necessary to remove the battery when it is full, because the charger turns off: does this also apply only when the machine is turned off or also when I am using it?

I read at a Superuser discussion that some notebook producers provide with battery savers which keep the battery level of charge within a certain range even when the notebook is connected to the AC grid: can this be a good solution? Can TLP be a solution for Ubuntu?

Comment: To me, this seems like a the answer is going to be based on your personal usage. If the laptop is always on AC power and you don't ever need to run on battery, then you *could* remove it. However, if you think you might need battery power, then the effort to remove and reinstall it is probably to high.

Comment: I know that based on my personal usage it would seem wise to remove altogether the battery. But many suggest not to remove it so to avoid to expose motherboard and hard disk to power surges, and also not everybody can afford a UPS for every place he is supposed to move to.

Comment: Messing with battery removal won't make a huge difference in its life.  However, the battery acts like a built-in UPS, so there is an advantage to leaving it in place.